# How to turn off monitors after period of activity using Group Policy? (SBS 2003)

Tags: group-policy

I am attempting to set our organization's workstation monitors to be turned off after a set period of time, via Group Policy.

Could someone guide me through how this can be achieved with SBS 2003?

Comment: What are your client computer OS'es? Anyhoo: try the Group Policy settings here: http://www.nojokeit.com/2011/02/group-policy-to-turn-off-display.html?m=1

Comment: @BigChris: Windows 7 and XP